# using mongoose populate in node typescript environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am unable to figure this out. I am using node express mongoose server with the code written in typescript. Getting error

> Property 'populate' does not exist on type 'Document | Aggregate | Model | Query'

for below code in my org.model.ts file:

```js
OrgSchema.pre("findById", function(next) {
  this.populate({
    path: "acs",
    select: "name -org"
  }).populate({
    path: "rcs",
    select: "name -org"
  });
  next();
});
```

Am I missing something? Because the same code works in a js file. I am still new to writing node code in typescript.

Comment: Can you give some more information on it, you are using findById but where is id passed to filter out the data although I am not using typescript but I guess id should be passed right.

Comment: You can use populate as 
populate([{ path: "acs", select: { "name -org": 1 } },
{ path: "rcs", select: { "name -org": 1 } } ])
Hope this helps

Comment: id is being passed as route parameter. And what you are suggesting is using array of object inside populate. But my issue is that in typescript it is not allowing me to use populate in modal file at all. But I am able to use it in controller file directly like this:

Comment: export async function getOrg(req: any, res: any, next: any) {
    const org = await Organisation.findById(req.params.id).populate({
        path: 'acs',
        select: 'name -org'
    }).populate({
        path: 'rcs',
        select: 'name -org'
    });
    if (!org) {
        return next(new APIError(`No Org found with id ${req.params.id}`, 404));
    }
    res.status(200).json(org);
}

Comment: But I wanted to write it as a query middleware

Comment: Can you add the all OrgSchema code, and the referenced schema codes?

Comment: So you want to populate data whenever data from this collection is fetched. 
To add this as an middleware please refer query functions supported here
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: @SuleymanSah you can see my Org model code here: https://codepen.io/bijay_ps/pen/RwNYaxN?editors=0010

Comment: @SureshShetiar will checkout the link you have shared and see if it helps me

Comment: @BijaySingh Please add this in place of your commented code in https://codepen.io/bijay_ps/pen/RwNYaxN?editors=0010
and check if it work and let me know the result.

`
var autoPopulate = function(next) {
  this.populate('acs');
  next();
};

OrgSchema
.pre('findOne', autoPopulate)
.pre('find', autoPopulate);
`

Comment: @SureshShetiar nope that didn't work

Comment: @BijaySingh try this, change "function" by =>

OrgSchema.pre("findById", (next) => {
  this.populate({
    path: "acs",
    select: "name -org"
  }).populate({
    path: "rcs",
    select: "name -org"
  });
  next();
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was my mistake I messed up. What I was trying to do is a "Virtual populate" and it was working fine as expected. Somehow I mixed the concepts of virtual populate and populate in query middleware. Apologies